# Needed Update to Server or Website to support AWS Certificate Rotation

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, ssl, web-config, ssl-certificate

I've received an email from Amazon Web Services regarding certificate rotation. I need to know whether I should make any changes to my EC2 or `Web.config` to make it support the new database certificate.

Rotating your SSL/TLS certificate: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL-certificate-rotation.html

Updating Applications to Connect to Microsoft SQL Server DB Instances Using New SSL/TLS Certificates: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/ssl-certificate-rotation-sqlserver.html

A sample connection string from the Web.config that I use (sensitive data omitted).

```
<add name="temp" connectionString="Server=someaddress.us-east-3.rds.amazonaws.com;
Port=3306;Database=somedatabase;Uid=someuserid;Pwd=somepassword" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

All my websites have a similar connection string that connects to the RDS database server.

Is there any change needed to be made to the web.config or the EC2 server to make my websites support the new certificate rotation.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what type of cert you're talking about.  Your connection string is for MySQL but you reference a SQLServer.  AWS also has ACM certs, which are deployed on load balancers or cloudfront.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make any changes since you are not using `SSL` certificate to connect to RDS. your website will continue to work as it is now without making any changes to your config. But you can consider using SSL to connect to your RDS in order to improve security in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you aren't using an SSL connection to your database, the certificate won't be used and you can update the certificate without any side effect.
This would have been the case if your connectionString included an sslmode as required:

```
<add
name="mySql"
providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
connectionString="...;SslMode=Required;" />
```

Since this is not the case, you can update your certificate right away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Web.config needs to changed definitely.The changes required are listed below.There might be additional changes based on the security group and vpc setup you have done.

1. You need to add SslMode=Required parameter to the connectionString
2. Also add a parameter SslCa=ca.pem

Download the https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2019-root.pem file from aws.

Comment: Others say I don't need to change it. If I don't intend to connect over SSL, what I need to change the web.config?